# how to get random values from the MySQL database table without repeating?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called topics and in that there is field called vTopicName.
I want to display random topics by clicking on the button without repeating them what should be the SQL query for it??

In controller I call

```
public function browse()
{
    $data['topic'] = $this->topics_model->get_random_topic();
    $topic = $data['topic']['vTopicName'];
    redirect("/$topic");

}
```

In the model there is

```
public function get_random_topic()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ws_topics ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

THis will redirect to domainname.com/topicname

Comment: You'll have to keep track of the ones already displayed, by, for example, setting a flag against those already used.  Show us what you've got so far and we'll be able to help you more.

Comment: I have used the below function in the codeigniter framework in the model:

Comment: public function get_random_topic()
 {
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ws_topics ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
  return $query->row_array();
 }

Comment: This will potentially return the same value on two subsequent calls.

Comment: @AleksG Assuming the page isn't being reloaded in between, they could just fetch all the topics in random order and serve them up one by one. It seems like in this case, one large query would be more efficient than repeating a small query with lots of temp data about what's already been retrieved.

Comment: @octern Read the question carefully: the OP wants to get the next random value on the reload.

Comment: page gets reloaded every time i click the button

Comment: @AleksG The OP says "by clicking the button" which could be a javascript or AJAX call; it doesn't necessarily need to reload the entire page (and toss out all information from previous queries). EDIT: Okay, comment above says that it does reload the entire page.

Comment: @octern Read the comment above yours.  Plus, AJAX is the same as reloading.

Comment: @AleksG Yes, you apparently viewed it during the 5 seconds I was editing it, just like I posted it during the seconds before the comment above mine showed up. Now I understand why the mods are always badgering people to take conversations like this to chat...

Comment: i have added the code in the question take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

First. **Using Database**

You should add a datetime field lets say 'displayed_on' in the same
    table, when you display a topic, set its the displayed_on to current
    time. Now, when you next fetch the records you can apply ascending
    sort to displayed_on field and limit the results to skip the ones
    that were displayed before (or recently displayed).

```
select vTopicName from (select * from topics order by rand() limit
    30) order by displayed_on asc limit 5;
```

Second. **Using Session**

You can also put all the displayed topics in a session variable and can skip them while fetching next bunch of topics.

```
$query = "select vTopicName from topics where topics.id not in (".implode(',',$_SESSION['displayed_topics']).") order by rand limit 5;
```

If there are few records in the table, you should reset the session variable when you get less than 5 records from the above query.

Comment: This will not ever return a result approaching 'random'. On the first past it's pseudo random but then each new cycle will be the same.

Comment: Think of a sub-query. like select vTopicName from (select * from topics order by rand() limit 30) order by displayed_on asc limit 5;

Comment: @NathanielFord "I want to display random topics without repeating them.. " *is* pseudorandom. Truly random would be "I want to display a random topic on each view.", and using a random method to grab a random entry in a large table would suffice.  The OP is asking for a pseudorandom solution though -- one of which is described in this answer.

Comment: @DavidCowden It's random on each pass, it just random-with-removal. This answer *now* describes a random solution, I agree. Note that I indicated this answer's original form would be pseudo random not on any sort of randomized function but based on how the database happened to return a set of unordered rows (which probably would have been based on insert time).

Comment: @NathanielFord random-with-removal == pseudorandom

Comment: In fact, we're not really using pseudorandom correctly here.  Pseudorandom means a "random" sequence that is deterministic.  Meaning the sequence generated will be repeated given the same seed.  Both your original solution and the OP's original solution were random with removal, you just did it in different ways.

Comment: You're arguing a point of semantics that doesn't help clarify the problem at hand. Mathematically speaking, I'll grant the definition of pseudorandom. That definition does not match what the OP was looking for, nor did the original solution of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will be your basic query:

```
SELECT * FROM vTopicName WHERE displayed = false ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
```

You will then have to 'flag' that topic as displayed. Hard to say exactly how to do that without knowing your primary id on the table, but here is an approximation:

```
UPDATE vTopicName SET displayed = true WHERE primaryId = <id of the row you got>
```

However, if you want different users to be affected differently, you will need a separate table to cover their actions:

```
SELECT * FROM vTopicName as topic 
  JOIN userActivity AS user ON topic.id = user.topicid 
 WHERE user.displayed = false ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

Then you need to update the `userActivity` table:

```
UPDATE userActivity SET displayed = true WHERE topicid = <topic id> AND id = <userid>
```

In order to ensure that users will have all topics available once they've seen everything you will also have to run this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(topicid) FROM userActivity WHERE id = <user id> AND displayed = false;
```

If this is equal to 0 (or some low number), you will then have to run:

```
UPDATE userActivity SET displayed = false WHERE id = <user id>;
```

Comment: this will create problem when multiple users are viewing the table if there are 10 topics and all of them are currently being viewed then all would be false so next user will not be able to see anything

Comment: So, that was not part of your specification, but you're now talking about a much larger issue. I'll try and modify my solution to provide for it.

Comment: @Aniket I have provided *a* solution, but you have poorly specified how and when you want your table to reset: you said no repeats - it is easy to get that functionality. Harder to get a particular pattern of repeats (such as when you run out of topics to show).

Comment: @Aniket Again, when you say 'this', what precisely do you mean? Do you mean a pseudo-random selection of a topic? Or do you mean a strictly random without repetition selection of a topic? These are distinct things.

Comment: by the saying no repeats i meant that the topic for example : "Apple" should not occur simultaneously

Comment: Please review your last comment and edit it so that it is an actual sentence with semantic meaning.

Comment: i click the button first time i get apple second time i click i get steve, third i get google, fourth i get microsoft and so on... what i dont want is 1st time click i get apple, 2nd time apple 3rd time google 4th time apple.....

Comment: I'm sure that it can be done without adding another table, though perhaps not entirely in SQL and almost certainly not without an additional column, and I wonder at the solution's elegance. You haven't specified whether you want random across users or sessions. You haven't specified whether it's ok to show 99 out of a hundred topics, and then repeat one before the 100th happens to come up. You haven't said if I walk away for two days and come back if it's ok for 'apple' to show up again. You need to define your needs better.

Comment: the order can be any its not an issue its just that i dont want apple to come twice: 1st time click apple 2nd time click apple this is main concern this should not happen

Comment: So 'apple, microsoft, apple, google, apple, tectronix' is a valid sequence? Is this valid on a per-user or per-request basis? If I make a request and get apple, you make a request and get microsoft, and I make another request I get apple again.

Comment: if there are say 10 topics so on clicking 11th time definitely the list will cycle again....

Comment: if i make request i get apple you make request you can also get apple or any other not an issue.....

Comment: Then what you're asking for is the two-table solution I provided, or one that is mathematically equivalent.

Comment: is there a way to do apple,google,microsoft,steve,nexus then again apple,google,microsoft,steve,nexus and so on??

Comment: Sure, but if you want to tie a particular cycle to a particular user, you need an additional table.

Comment: i dont want any particular cycle the order of the sequence may be any to any user i dont care. This is just example apple,google,microsoft,steve,nexus then again apple,google,microsoft,steve,nexus and so on again i am saying i dont care about order, apple might come first, last in between whatever let it come....

Comment: All I can suggest at this point is that you try some solutions, including the one I posted, and see what is closest to what you're looking for. I believe I understand what you're asking for, but it's not possible without an additional table; that is the only way (with these constraints) you can get different users to not overrun each other.